# Show current user as "Me" in select tag

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have used the below-written code to select the users

```
def user_for_select
    User.pluck(:name, :id).unshift(['All', 'all'])
end
```

But I want to display the current user's name as "Me" in the select tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like:

```
def user_for_select
  User
    .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{current_user.id} THEN 'ME' ELSE name END AS name, id")
    .unshift(['All', 'all'])
end
```

Tested in my own rails console (Rails 4.2.6):

```
Admin.pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{u.id} THEN 'ME' ELSE full_name END AS name, id").unshift(['All', 'all'])
# (0.6ms)  SELECT CASE WHEN id = 7 THEN 'ME' ELSE full_name END AS name, id FROM "admins"
# => [["All", "all"], ["arup rakshit", 1], ["ME", 7], ["pinaki das", 2], ["mina das", 3], ["proloy das", 4], ["mouli roy", 5], ["pisi das", 6]]
```

EDIT: If the method is class method like below.

```
class User < AR
  class << self
    def user_for_select(user)
      self
        .pluck("CASE WHEN id = #{user.id} THEN 'ME' ELSE name END AS name, id")
        .unshift(['All', 'all'])
    end
  end
end
```

Now from view call it like :

```
user_for_select(current_user)
```

Comment: small typo. slect => select

Comment: @AlokSwain Thank you.

Comment: I have written this method in the User model and it's showing me an error of undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Comment: replace it with self.id. But I have some other typos. Working on it. give me 2 mins

Comment: @AasishSharma Now I gave you correct code. it will work. just replace `current_user.id` with `self.id`. It will be fine

Comment: class << self
    def user_for_select
      User.select("CASE WHEN id = #{self.id} THEN 'ME' ELSE name END AS name, id").attributes.to_a.unshift(['All', 'all'])
    end
  end

Comment: undefined method `id' for #<Class:0x007fc798ca1fb8>
Did you mean?  ids

Comment: user_for_select method is under << self

Comment: How are you calling the method from the view let me know, I can then help you to fix. I got your issue now why `id` error comes

Comment: = select_tag(:u_id, options_for_select(User.user_for_select, selected: params[:u_id]), class: "input-sm form-control", onchange: "this.form.submit();")

Answer (score 1):

Just match user id with current user's id

```
User.pluck(:name, :id).map{|user| [(user[1] == current_user.id ? "Me" : user[0]), user[1]]}.unshift(['All', 'all'])
```